# Why firefox and IE not refresh page after click button?

Tags: javascript, php, refresh

Why firefox and IE not refresh page after click button ?

After click button , it's will show "OK." and then refresh page.

I test on chrome, opera, safari it's OK.
but on firefox and IE not refresh 
How can i do ?

test_1.php

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="myForm" action="test_2.php" method="post">
    <button id="sub">Send</button>
</form>
<span id="result"></span>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#sub").click( function() {
 $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"), 
         $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(), 
         function(info){ $("#result").html(info); 
   });
 clearInput();
});

$("#myForm").submit( function() {
  return false; 
});
</script>
```

test_2.php

```
<?php
  echo "OK.";
  echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV = 'Refresh' Content = '2'>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to reload the page if you use AJAX? It completely defies the need. The meta tag lives in the head and is not executed from an Ajax call in most browsers

In test2.php you can do

```
// save your data here
$status = someFunctionReturningSomeString(parameters);
header("location: test_1.php?status=$status");
```

and back in test1.php,  test that status and show it to user:

```
<? 
$status = $_GET["status"]; // perhaps some cleaning is needed too 
if (isset($status)) { 
   echo "<script>$(function() $("#result").html('".$status."')});</script>";
} ?>
<form id="myForm" action="test_2.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

***NOTE***: Do NOT echo anything before a header or you will get *Cannot modify header information - headers already sent*

---

If you MUST reload you can better do the following than return a meta tag

```
$("#myForm").on("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // cancel the form
  $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"), 
     $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(), 
     function(info){ $("#result").html(info); 
     // allow the user to see the result perhaps?
     setTimeout(function() { location.reload(1)},3000); 
  });
  clearInput();
});
```

Comment: in test_2.php change to `echo "OK."; header("location: test_1.php");` ?

Comment: in test_1.php change to ?

`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="myForm" action="test_2.php" method="post">
<span id="result"></span>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#myForm").on("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // cancel the form
  $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"), 
     $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(), 
     function(info){ $("#result").html(info); 
     // allow the user to see the result perhaps?
     setTimeout(function() { location.reload(1)},3000); 
  });
  clearInput();
});
</script>`

Comment: And in test_2.php change to ? `echo "OK."; header("location: test_1.php");`

Comment: Yes. just replace your jquery with mine. Also Never echo before headers and no need to echo after a location header

Comment: it"s WORK but show some error message , how can i do ?

**Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home1/myrootweb/public_html/test_2.php:2) in /home1/myrootweb/public_html/test_2.php on line 3**


this is code
`<?php
  echo "OK.";
  header("location: test_1.php");
?>`

Comment: Please pay attention to me and the meaning of the error message. I already said: ***NEVER*** echo anything before headers and no need to echo anything when sending a location header. REMOVE the echo!

Comment: I must to echo text "ok" , how can i do please ?

Comment: No you must not. You can do `header("location: test_1.php?status=ok");` and in test1 test that status and show it to user: `if ($_GET["status"]=="ok") echo "<script>$(function() $("#result").html('OK')});</script>";`

Comment: and i must to insert to mysql too , how can i do ? thank

Comment: This is not e-lancing! I have answered your question. Add the sql before the header. See update

Answer (score -3):

for you are working with jQuery you could do this:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
     location.reload();
 });
</script>
```